# JSF Delete Row on Button Click

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have some issues in deleting a row on click of a button. I have a datatable, which contains 5 columns. The fifth column is a button. I have a requirement, where, when I click on the button, the row data corresponding to the button needs to be deleted. Im trying to populate the column values using a datamodel. Below is the code that I have written to acheive the row deletion. But the row is not getting deleted.

```
<h:commandButton id="buttonID1"  image="/images/drappimages/delete.png" style="width:15px ;" actionListener="#{adminBean.delete}" >  
<f:ajax  render="adminTableID" ></f:ajax>  
</h:commandButton>
```

The listener method is specified below

```
public void delete(ActionEvent event)  
{  
    deleteFlag = true;  
    int rowIndex = adminVODataModel.getRowIndex() ;  
    AdminVO admminData = adminVODataModel.getRowData();  
    System.out.println("The rowIndex that needs to be actioned is :"+ rowIndex);  
    System.out.println("The adminVOList is :"+ adminVOList.size());  
    adminVOList.remove(rowIndex) ;  
    adminVOList.remove(adminData) ;  
    System.out.println("the VOList now is "+ adminVOList.size());  
    adminVODataModel = new ListDataModel<AdminVO>(adminVOList) ;  
    setAdminScheduleVODataModel(adminVODataModel);  

}
```

Im using the adminVODataModel  to populate the datatable. Im trying to remove the corresponding row using the above code. But the row is not getting deleted.

Please Assist. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You should update your table after deletion

just add `update="@form"` to your `<p:ajax`. In case you got some `h:panelGroup` wrapper, you can place its id instead of `@form` in the update.

b.t.w I think that in 3.4 you can place table id in the target of the `update` attribute too (not sure if that was possible in prior to 3.4)

since you moved to `h:commandButton` , try

`render="@form"` or `render="somePanelGroudIDThatWrapsTheTable"`

also

don't do both `adminVOList.remove(rowIndex);`  and `adminVOList.remove(adminData) ;`
if you got the right index use it to remove the entry

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the response. It did work when I use update="@form" in <p:ajax>. But the issue is, on consecutive clicks of the delete button, the row that has already been deleted seems to appear back.  I.e initially when I click rowIndex 1, the row gets deleted. The second time, when I click on an other row, say rowindex 5, the row corresponding to the rowindex 5 gets deleted. But the row data corresponding to rowIndex1 seems to appear again.

Comment: Have you checked whether the data is getting removed from your adminVOList ?

Comment: @vr3w3c9 either check that you are deleting the right index or instead of deleting the index you can pass the row var and remove it from your list , instead of `listener` in p:ajax use something like `action="#{adminBean.deleteWithArg(rowObj)}"` , seems that you are not removing properly from  the list/model

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the response. I have updated the above code and Im getting the corresponding row data and deleting the same from the list. Im using f:ajax and trying to render the datatable once the delete button gets executed to show the updated table data. But Im still facing some issues. The action listener gets invoked, but the table data does not get refreshed.

Comment: @vr3w3c9 try as i said `render="@form"` or `render="somePanelGroudIDThatWrapsTheTable"`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Daniel. I have tried to render the panelgroup id where the datatable exists. I gave render="adminPanelgroup". where adminPanelgroup is the id of the panelgroup. This does not seem to work. It just loads only the 1st row in the datatable & displays "<f:ajax> contains an unknown id 'adminPanelgroup' - cannot locate it in the context of the component buttonID1". I tried render="@form". This works, but only for the first click.The row doesnt get deleted on consecutive clicks.

Comment: seems like there are some issue with your deletion code in the bean , what does your print outs shows? are you really deleting/removing the right rows?

Comment: Yes Im deleting the right rows. I have also updated the code that I have written to delete the rows in my first post.

Comment: print out your list that is the source of the table , look at it after you deleting the entry + place a breakpoint/printout at the list getter to see whats going on...